# jQuery doesn't open a page in the new tab

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to open an URL on the new tab. The following code, opens it on the same tab:

```
$.post('insert_home.php',{
    UPDATECSSGOLD:'selected'}).done(function(data){
        alert ('THEME SUCCESSFULLY CHANGED!');
        window.location.replace("../WebPages/Home.php");                        
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$.post('insert_home.php',{
     UPDATECSSGOLD:'selected'}).done(function(data){
         alert ('THEME SUCCESSFULLY CHANGED!');
         window.open("../WebPages/Home.php", '_blank');                
});
```

This will open geven `URL` in the new tab.

Description:

> The open() method creates a new secondary browser window, similar to
>   choosing New Window from the File menu. The strUrl parameter specifies
>   the URL to be fetched and loaded in the new window. If strUrl is an
>   empty string, then a new blank, empty window (URL about:blank) is
>   created with the default toolbars of the main window.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: It still opens your page but at the same window?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('insert_home.php',{
     UPDATECSSGOLD:'selected'}).done(function(data){
         alert ('THEME SUCCESSFULLY CHANGED!');
         window.open("../WebPages/Home.php", '_blank');                
});
```

adding `_blank` helps us to open the page in a new tab.

Just like in html
Example of html

```
<a href="path" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to:

```
 var win=window.open("../WebPages/Home.php", '_blank');
 win.focus();
```

but be aware that it is ultimately up to the browser how it will open the new page - new tab, new window or same window.